# csvsimple creating multiple lines out of one entry

Tags: tables, multicolumn, csv, csvsimple

Data looks like this:

```
name,job,age
John,student,21
Frederik,student,18
Johnson,professor,49
```

I'd like to generate a table, that when for the first time a new job show up (the list is sorted by job), it generates a new table row, with just the `job`, and a row with two columns `name & age` otherwise have two just the two columns.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{student} \\
\hline
John & 21 \\
Frederik & 18 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{ |c|}{professor}\\
\hline
Johnson & 49\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Any idea if csvsimple supports that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes ;-)

Here is my suggestion for a complete solution. It does not use the predefined `tabular` options, but inserts the `tabular` environment settings directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{mylist.csv}
name,job,age
John,student,21
Frederik,student,18
Johnson,professor,49
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  head to column names,
  before line={%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\job}{\myjob}}
      {\\}%
      {\xdef\myjob{\job}%
       \\\hline\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\myjob}\\\hline}%
  },
  before first line={%
    \xdef\myjob{\job}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline%
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\myjob}\\\hline%
  },
  late after line=,
  late after last line={\\\hline\end{tabular}},
]{mylist.csv}{}{\name & \age}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code produces the same thing, but uses `\csvloop` instead of `\csvreader`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{mylist.csv}
name,job,age
John,student,21
Frederik,student,18
Johnson,professor,49
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvloop{
  file=mylist.csv,
  head to column names,
  before line=%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\job}{\myjob}}{%
      \\%
    }{%
      \xdef\myjob{\job}%
      \\\hline\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\myjob}\\\hline%
    },
  before first line=%
    \xdef\myjob{\job}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline%
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\myjob}\\\hline,
  command=\name & \age,
  late after line=,
  late after last line=\\\hline\end{tabular},
}

\end{document}
```